# Checking a list of proxies with aiohttp/async

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to use aiohttp and async to scrape a list of proxies and check if they work with a specific URL (-> status code 200). If so, I want to add them to a new list of working proxies. I did that with requests before and it worked fine, but it was very slow, therefore I am trying to make it work with an asynchronous approach. While I made the scraping part work, I cant make the checking part run:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random
import asyncio
import aiohttp

URL1 = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/'
URL2 = 'https://api.proxyscrape.com/v2/?request=getproxies&protocol=http&timeout=2900&country=all&ssl=all&anonymity=elite&simplified=true'


async def proxy_db():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(URL1) as resp1:
            text1 = await resp1.read()
            soup1 = BeautifulSoup(text1.decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')
            proxy_list_fpl = []
            for items1 in soup1.select("#proxylisttable tbody tr"):
                proxy_list_fpl.append(':'.join([item.text for item in items1.select("td")[:2]]))
            print(len(proxy_list_fpl))
        async with session.get(URL2) as resp2:
            text2 = await resp2.read()
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(text2.decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')
            proxy_list_ps = []
            for items2 in soup2:
                proxy_list_ps = items2.split()
            print(len(proxy_list_ps))
    templist = list(set(proxy_list_fpl + proxy_list_ps))
    proxy_list = ["http://" + s for s in templist]
    print(len(proxy_list))
    return proxy_list

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
proxies = loop.run_until_complete(proxy_db())
print(proxies)
loop.close()

# Until here it works fine. Im new to python and asyncio, so there might be a more 
# efficient way of coding this, however it already saved 50% time compared to my requests method before


working_proxy = []


async def fetch(session, url, proxy):
    async with session.get(url, proxy = proxies) as response:
        if response.status != 200:
            response.raise_for_status()
        return await response.text

async def fetch_all(session, url, proxy):
    tasks = []
    for proxy in proxies:
        task = asyncio.create_task(fetch(session, url, proxy))
        tasks.append(task)
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return results

async def main():
    url = "http://httpbin.org/ip"
    proxy = proxies
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        page = await fetch_all(session, url, proxy)
        if page.status == 200:
            working_proxy.append(proxies)
            print(len(working_proxy))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Resulting in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Dropbox/Python/5APR/Web_Scraping/asyncio_test.py", line 179, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Users/xxx/Dropbox/Python/5APR/Web_Scraping/asyncio_test.py", line 173, in main
    page = await fetch_all(session, url, proxy)
  File "/Users/xxx/Dropbox/Python/5APR/Web_Scraping/asyncio_test.py", line 166, in fetch_all
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "/Users/xxx/Dropbox/Python/5APR/Web_Scraping/asyncio_test.py", line 156, in fetch
    async with session.get(url, proxy = proxies) as response:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 415, in _request
    proxy = URL(proxy)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/yarl/_url.py", line 158, in __new__
    raise TypeError("Constructor parameter should be str")
TypeError: Constructor parameter should be str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I would appreciate any ideas or hints on how to make this run. Im new to Python and coding in general, so I am also happy about any hints about bad practice/style or more efficient ways of coding. Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: I'll take a blind shot and say that `proxy = proxies` is the problem. This function only takes 1 proxy, not several. This is why you get the error; it gets a whole list of proxies instead of just a string representing one.

Comment: @MikaelÖhman Thanks for your reply! I changed the proxy list for a fix proxy address, unfortunately still resulting in the same error.

Comment: And you have verified that the single proxy you pass in is in fact a `str` and not just, for example, a list with just 1 element?